# LCD monitor 2033 out of rang in ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, screen, monitor

i have a problem in ubuntu 13.04 when i want install or login .
i installed ubuntu with a crt monitor but when to login with lcd monitor , i dont have screen ( out of rang )
my monitor is samsung lcd syncmaster 2033

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the nomodeset option to the kernel when booting. Check [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters) out for instructions on how to pass kernel parameters at boot-time.